# How to find the conditional minimum of a filtered column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I would like to find the conditional minimum from a column of data, but have it respond to data filtering.

I have a sheet in excel with a summary section at the top, some graphs plotting various aspects of the data, and the data further down.
The data can be filtered, which updates the graphs, but it does not update the summary section.
The summary section show things like min, max, average, and stdev.
How do I make these respond to data filtering while also being conditional?
Essentially: find the minimum value in column A when column B is equal to X and update the result if any of the columns are filter.

I've looked at `SUBTOTAL`, but it does not allow conditions.
There is also functions such as `SUMPRODUCT((SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(INDEX($A$1:$A$10,1,1),ROW($A$1:$A$10)-ROW(INDEX($A$1:$A$10,1,1)),0))=1),($B$1:$B$10="value"),$C$1:$C$10)` which calculate the sum of column C, when column B equals "value" and updates when the filter is updated (given that the filter includes columns A, B and C).

Comment: If you got Excel 2019 or 365 you can use function `MAXIFS`. If not, you'll need an array formula to get max values of a range based on conditions. Maybe you can combine SUBTOTAL with an array formula to get it done?

Comment: Can you just put an extra column in that only shows the values if the condition is met, and then find the minumum on that column using subtotal?

Answer (score 1):

If you can add one helper column that would be very helpfull for you, e.g.:

[image]

[image]

Formula used in `D2`:

```
=SUBTOTAL(3,A2)
```

This formula will end up leaving a 1 for visible cells, a 0 for invisible ones. You could choose to hide this column. We can test against this column in a multi-criteria array formula.

Formula in `F1`:

```
=MIN(IF((B2:B7="Z")*(D2:D7=1),C2:C7))
```

Confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56782851/how-to-find-the-minimum-and-maximum-in-a-certain-date-range/56785446#56785446) example.

You can do the same type of formula's for your other needs (MAX, AVERAGE)